# how to combine two commands into one

Tags: docker, dockerfile, chmod

Please advise how I can combine this commands in one but I don't need install npm in /opt/app-root folder

```
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /opt/app-root
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /app && npm i
```

Answer (score 0):

You've already combined two commands on the second line; you can use the same method to combine the first and second lines.

```
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /opt/app-root && chmod -R ug+rwx /app && npm i
```

You could also just give both arguments to `chmod` at once though.

```
RUN chmod -R ug+rwx /opt/app-root /app && npm i
```